# How to order a nested list in R

Tags: python, r

I need the code to be in R
Exemple
I have a list:

```
[[0,'A',50.1],
[1,'B',50.0],
[2,'C',50.2],
[3,'D',50.7],
[4,'E',50.3]]
```

I want to order it based on the 3rd elemnts only so I get a result like this

```
[[1,'B',50.0],
[0,'A',50.1],
[2,'C',50.2],
[4,'E',50.3],
[3,'D',50.7]]
```

and then reorder the index so the Final result would be

```
Final = [[0,'B',50.0],
[1,'A',50.1],
[2,'C',50.2],
[3,'E',50.3],
[4,'D',50.7]]
```

and then I have the indexes in some grouping

```
G = [[0,1],[1,3][2,3,4]]
```

I want based on G as indexes of Final have the Grouping like this

```
[['B','A'],['A','E']['C','E','D']]
```

I already have the code in python, but I need the same code in R

```
L = [[i, *x[1:]] for i, x in enumerate(sorted(L, key=lambda x: x[2]))]
print (L)
[[0, 'B', 50.0], [1, 'A', 50.1], [2, 'C', 50.2], [3, 'E', 50.3], [4, 'D', 50.7]]
out = [[L[y][1] for y in x] for x in G]
print (out)
[['B', 'A'], ['A', 'E'], ['C', 'E', 'D']]
```

Comment: You can convert your list to a dataframe (`as.data.frame(my_list)`) and use base R or {dplyr}'s or {data.table}'s plethora of dataframe operations. If needed, reconvert to list (`as.list`). To convert from Python array to R list, see e.g. https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector

Comment: Thank you so much, I already have the input data as list, the problem for me is how to implement the same python code into R

Comment: please share your sample data.frame and G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
LL <- L |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  arrange(x) |>
  mutate(id=sort(L$id))

lapply(G, \(x) LL$v1[LL$id %in% x])
```

---

```
[[1]]
[1] "B" "A"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "E" "D"
```

---

Data:

```
L <- list(id=0:4, v1=LETTERS[1:5], x = c(50.1, 50.0, 50.2, 50.7, 50.3))
G <- list(c(0,1), c(1,3), c(2,3,4))
```

Libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
```